# How to find out Euclidean Minimum Spanning tree using CGAL library?

Tags: c++, triangulation, cgal, delaunay

I have a set of 2-D points, and considering every point connected to every other one with an "edge" with weight equal to the distance between them, I need to find the MST of the resulting graph.
I am using the fact that EMST is always a subgraph of the delaunay triangulation of this field. I need the triangles' as a list of edges to make a graph from it and then run Kruskal over it.

Also, Do I have to go the Delaunay triangulation way, or is there a direct function for it?

Kindly give a sample code for figuring out which headers to include, which namespace to use etc. with your answer for either question, if possible.

Comment: It might help if you would mention the programming language you're using.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you don't directly use boost like shown [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/example/kruskal-example.cpp).

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Its C++ in VS2012.

Comment: @sloriot That is just ordinary Kruskal. That would lead to running the algorithm on O(n^2) edges. I have heard that that is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

In 2D, the number of edges of a triangulation is linear. Once the Delaunay triangulation is computed using [cgal](/questions/tagged/cgal), you can use an implementation of minimal spanning tree on graph. See the wikipedia page [Euclidean minimum spanning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_minimum_spanning_tree#Algorithms_for_computing_EMSTs_in_two_dimensions).